# Find the uniform search technique for the River Crossing puzzle

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have to use a uninformed search technique to solve the following problem.

The game is like:

On side of the river, there is a Policeman, a Robber, a woman in a red-dress and her two children, a woman in a yellow dress and her two children. There is a boat that can carry atmost two persons. The children cannot drive the boat. 
If the policeman is absent then the robber will kill the people. If the red-dress woman is absent then the yellow-dressed woman will kill the red-dressed woman’s children and vice versa.

I am confused as usual. Please help me figure it out.
The problem and how can it be solved (without programming) is shown in the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSusAZBSWwg

Thank you.

Comment: You need to model the problem in the form of a decision tree and then solve it ([by brute-force](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/usearch/)) - how you model the problem, that's your assignment.

Comment: You mean dept first or breadth first tree?

Comment: For a tree such small, does not matter as long as you track game states that you have already encountered (i. e., find oh, the wolf is there and other guys are here and it already cost me less or equal to reach the position than in the current branch, so the current branch makes no sense to follow).

Answer (score -1):

Problems like River Crossing Puzzle, Sokoban or Lemmings are solved normally with Brute-Force-Search in the gametree. The domain is specified declarative as rules (moves are possible or not), and a function which determines the amount of points which are reached by a policy (policy = plan through the gametree). The solver has the aim to find a good policy. The best hardware for doing this is a quantum computer with unlimited speed for testing as much as possble moves per second.

The reason why this is not practicaly is because of a phenomenon which is called "combinatorial explosion", first introduced by James Lighthill in year 1973 for prooving that artifical intelligence is not ready for use in realworld. The answer to that problem is, to use alternative strategies which have noting to do with brute-force-search.

One possibility is to use heuristics which are hardcoded into programcode. Often these heuristics are called macroaction or motion primitives. An example would be "bring-robber-to-other-side". This subfunction executes a predefined number of actions. Another macroaction could be "check-if-two-woman-are-on-the-same-side". To implement such kind of strategy for the complete game is a hard task. Not because of high cpu usage, but because of every detail has to coded into software.